# How to use solo.searchText for searching some text consisting of special characters

Tags: android, robotium

I am using robotium to test an android project.I have a testcase where i need to test a message consisting of special characters is posted correctly.
So I created a constant consisting of special characters :

```
public static final String PostMessageWithSpecialchars = "Hey hi,* Have a good day*.:()[]-=/&!?"'+;@#";
```

and i am using following code to search it and assert that the posted message is exactly like the message in the constant PostMessageWithSpecialchars

```
assertTrue(solo.searchText(PostMessageWithSpecialchars));
```

but the test fails at assertTrue line.
What to do to search the PostMessageWithSpecialchars text?I dont want to use escape characters because that will ignore special characters.I want to make sure that the special characters in the PostMessageWithSpecialchars message are posted correctly.

Comment: Hi, can you specify what exactly do you want to find. searchText use regular expression, so you need to create proper pattern.

Comment: I want to find that the message in PostMessageWithSpecialchars when posted is shown exactly as it is...so after sending that message i am using assertTrue(solo.searchText(PostMessageWithSpecialchars)); to check that but the assert is getting failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method solo.searchText() accept regex pattern. In your search string you are using special characters that is used for patters. You can quote them to find any text:

```
assertTrue(solo.searchText(Pattern.quote(PostMessageWithSpecialchars)));
```

Comment: Pattern.quot what does it do?Does it ignores special characters?

Comment: Yes, it quote special characters, so regex will perform search for characters rather then accept it as command.

Comment: but i don't want to ignore or escape special characters. B'coz when i am entering a message like "hi ** all" i want to assert that those "**" are posted properly.

Comment: Quote command doesn't ignore characters it just say that you want to find text. Again searchText use regex pattern, so if you want to find text with special characters then use quote method. Can you provide the example string, cause i am confuse what do you want to find. If you have text like "hi * all" then use Pattern.quote if you want to find text like "hi Your name" then you need to create proper regex pattern.

Comment: i have provided the text that i want to search in the description...it is provided in the PostMessageWithSpecialchars constant..