# solo.searchText does not identify "$"

Tags: android, search, robotium

I am using solo.searchText function in my robotium testcases. I am passing the text as "$ testdata" for searching. But it is not detecting the text even if the text is there in the screen. Do we need to handle special charecters before using solo.searchText()? Please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Pattern.quote()` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240700/how-to-use-solo-searchtext-for-searching-some-text-consisting-of-special-charact) to search for special characters that would otherwise be interpreted as regular expressions.

```
solo.searchText(Pattern.quote(stringWithSpecialCharacters))
```

Comment: actually i am writing this search code in a for loop. there are many texts have to searched which has no special characters. So if i am using this function will it affect other text search?

Comment: No, it should not negatively impact searches without special characters. It simply converts any special characters (if there are any) to string format so they won't be accepted as regex.